# Obtaining CDI Alternatives programatically

Tags: java, cdi

I had the following interface

```
public interface A {
    InputStream getPdf(String value);
}
```

with several implementations, each of them marked by a qualifier. For example:

```
@Dependent
@Vac
public class VacA implements A {
   @Override public getPdf(String value) {...}
}
```

Now, I had to add an alternative implementation for each of the qualified beans. Easy enough:

```
@Dependent
@Vac
@Alternative
public class AltVacA implements A {
   @Override public InputStream getPdf(String value) {...}
}
```

and of course I reflected that at *beans.xml*.

But later I was told that the logic used would be decided at runtime. Instead of a @Provider, I opted for creating a third implementation that works as a facade<sup>1</sup>:

```
@Dependent
@Vac
@Alternative
public class TempVacA implements A {
   @Override public InputStream getPdf(String value) {
       if (useVacA()) {
          return this.getPdfVacA(value);
       }
       return this.getPdfAltVacA(value);
   }
   ...
}
```

Then it comes the issue: in *getPdfVacA* I can programmatically get a *VacA* instance with the following code:

```
Instance<VacA> instance = CDI.current().select(VacA.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Vac>() {});
VacA provider = instance.get();
return provider.getPdf(value);
```

but if I try to do the same with *AltVacA*,

```
Instance<VacA> instance = CDI.current().select(AltVacA.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Vac>() {});
AltVacAprovider = instance.get();
return provider.getPdf(value);
```

I get a message that no matching class with the proper qualifiers has been found.

I did find that Alternatives must be activated in order to be retrieved, and sure enough, I did remove the *@Alternative* from *AltVacA* and the code does work.

But I do not like that now I have two "default" implementations of *A* with the *@Vac* qualifier; if I were ever to delete *TempVacA* I would have issues due to it and I would have to work one of those as alternative.

It would be nice to find a way to programmatically retrieve alternatives, but I cannot find any way to do this. Otherwise, there is any be a better approach for this task than the one I have used?

I am using wildfly 14 on JDK 8.

<sup>1</sup>Maybe a little weird, but as long as I know this design decission does not affect the issue stated in the question.

Comment: Consider injecting a `Map<String, A>` into `TempVacA` which contains all available implementations, with the key related to `value`.  Then use the `value` to determine which implementation should be used.